# Codeigniter 3 Transaction doesn't work error handling

Tags: php, transactions, codeigniter-3

```
public function addData()
{
    $this->db->trans_begin();
    try{
        if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE){
            $menu = array(
                'menu_name' => $label,
                'url' => $path,
                'parent_id' => $parent,
                'icon' => $icon,
                'status' => 1,
                'created_at' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
                'updated_at' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
            );

            $this->db->insert('tbl_menu', $menu);
            $last_menu_id = $this->db->insert_id();

            foreach ($roles as $key => $value) {
                $permission = array(
                    'role_id' => $value,
                    'menu_id' => $last_menu_id,
                    'status' => 1,
                    'created_at' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
                    'updated_at' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
                );
                $this->db->insert('tbl_permissions', $permission);
            }
            $this->session->set_flashdata('success','Menu Added Successfully...!!!');
        }else{
            $this->session->set_flashdata('error','You have to fill fields...!!!');
        }
        $this->db->trans_commit();

        redirect('menu/add'); 
    }catch(Exception $e){
        $this->db->trans_rollback();
        $this->session->set_flashdata('error',$e->getMessage());
        redirect('menu/add');
    }
}
```

Hi guys, 
In here 2nd table name is incorrect.but when I run the code it doesn't return a error & doesn't rollback(it inserts data to first table).what's the issue..?

Answer (score 0):

```
    $this->db->trans_begin();
    if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE){
        $menu = array(
            'menu_name' => $label,
            'url' => $path,
            'parent_id' => $parent,
            'icon' => $icon,
            'status' => 1,
            'sequence' => $sequence,
            'created_at' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
            'updated_at' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
        );

        $this->db->insert('tbl_menu', $menu);
        $last_menu_id = $this->db->insert_id();

        foreach ($roles as $key => $value) {
            $permission = array(
                'role_id' => $value,
                'menu_id' => $last_menu_id,
                'status' => 1,
                'created_at' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
                'updated_at' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
            );
            $this->db->insert('tbl_permissions', $permission);
        }
        $this->db->trans_complete();
        $trans_status = $this->db->trans_status();
        if($trans_status == FALSE){
            $this->session->set_flashdata('error','Some issue with data inserting..!!!');
            $this->db->trans_rollback();
        }else{
            $this->session->set_flashdata('success','Menu Added Successfully...!!!');
            $this->db->trans_commit();
        }
    }else{
        $this->session->set_flashdata('error','You have to fill fields...!!!');
        $this->db->trans_rollback();
    }
```

Finally I tried like this.it worked.removed the "try-catch"